# Function in external jquery file not working

Tags: jquery, html

I saw many js files which we include in our html page and it start working. I have made simple function to check how it works, I made external file and then included it in my web page but it is not working. my code is....

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="face.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cl">check code</div>
</body>
```

//jquery

```
function mtLoan(){

    $('.cl').css('background-color','#ff0000')

}
```

Comment: is your external js is face.js?

Comment: when this function `mtLoan` is being called??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

***HTML***

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="face.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cl">check code</div>
</body>
```

***JS CODE***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cl').on('click', function(){
       mtLoan();
    });
    function mtLoan(){
       $('.cl').css('background-color','#ff0000')
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hhBFZ/11/

Comment: inform me if modification needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling mtLoan anywhere. Change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.cl').css('background-color','#ff0000')
})
```

Comment: But I saw many jquery file which does not use document ready method

Comment: (document).ready is used so that the DOM and all it's dependencies has loaded before firing the script to avoid any issues

Comment: You can do it within the mtLoan function but you must call the function for it to work

Answer (score 0):

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="face.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
  mtLoan();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling this function anywhere, use  [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event to init your javascript, so your HTML will be aware of Javascript and vise versa.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.cl').css('background-color','#ff0000')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function inside doccument.ready function in the external js file or in the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use document ready event. This video tutorial site explains very nicely some general examples. http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-day-2/

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the js files you have added are showing in browser or not.
And the jquery function you have written is wrong.
where you have defined : mtLoan() ??